# [Q]:Syntax error in creating UDF in mysql

Tags: mysql, udf

hey guys sorry for this noob question, i am trying to learn mysql but i am stuck at creating udf. can someone please explain why this is syntax error and what is the possible fix. thanks

```
create FUNCTION temtotalgrades
(@p_Studid int, @p_year int)
RETURNS int 
BEGIN
return (SELECT CONCAT( fname, " ", lname,  '\n', GROUP_CONCAT
(student_grades.subject_id,  " = ", student_grades.final SEPARATOR  '\n' ) ) 
FROM student_grades
INNER JOIN student ON student.studid = student_grades.studid
where student.studid = @p_Studid and year = @p_year     
GROUP BY student_grades.studid)
END
```

Comment: This is not a UDF.  This is a stored function.  The former is written in C, and uses the plugin hooks to actually add a global function to the server; the latter is written in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few points...

A function returns a single value.

The value being return needs to correspond to the type specified for the RETURNS.

The `@` character is used for naming *user-defined variables*, not for procedure/function variables/parameters.

As an example, try something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION temtotalgrades
( p_studid INT
, p_year   INT
) RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
BEGIN
  DECLARE v_myret VARCHAR(4000);
  SELECT CONCAT( s.fname
               , ' '
               , s.lname
               , '\n'
               , GROUP_CONCAT(
                   CONCAT(g.subject_id,' = ',g.final)
                   SEPARATOR '\n'
                 )
         )
    INTO v_myret
    FROM student_grades g
    JOIN student s ON s.studid = g.studid
   WHERE s.studid = p_studid
     AND g.year   = p_year;
  RETURN v_myret;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```